# Comparar dos array y contar las incidencias

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo dos array

```
$array1=('18753933','18753933','18771982')
$array2=('18753933','18771982')
```

Estoy recorriendo cada uno para comparar los valores que son iguales en cada array

```
        var  contarArticulosCargados=0;
        for(var $i=0;$i<$array1.length;$i++)
        {
            for(var $j=0;$j<$array2.length;$j++)
            {

                if($array1[$i]===$array[$j])
                {
                    contarArticulosCargados++;

                }
            }
        }
        console.log(contarArticulosCargados);
```

Este ejemplo que he puesto en mi código funciona bien, es decir, yo estoy haciendo la comparación y funciona sin problema.

Que quiero hacer? (Es lo que no tengo idea de como hacerlo)

Como pueden ver en $array1 esta el valor 18753933 y en el $array2 también esta el valor 18753933

Lo que quiero es que cuando el valor se repita este se cuente, en  el $array1 el valor 18753933 esta 2 veces y el valor 18771982 esta 1 vez.

Yo quiero ver algo como esto:

```
18753933  se repite: 2 
18771982  se repite: 1
```

podrian darme una idea de que es lo que me falta? siempre me cuesta hacer comparaciones entre arrays. Gracias.

Comment: Es javascript o php?

Answer (score 2):

Para este caso te puedo ofrecer dos soluciones, una mas sencilla de entender que la otra pero menos eficiente, y otra un poco mas compleja pero mas eficiente.

### Solución A

La primera solucion es obtener el resultado deseado haciendo uso de las funciones `Array.prototype.map` y `Array.prototype.filter` de la siguiente forma:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
const arr2 = [2,2,4,6,6,6,8,8,0]

const res = arr1.map(val => ({ val, count: arr2.filter(subval => subval === val).length }))

console.log(res)
```

El resultado mostrado por consola sera algo similar a esto dependiendo de donde lo ejecutes:

```
[ { val: 1, count: 0 },
  { val: 2, count: 2 },
  { val: 3, count: 0 },
  { val: 4, count: 1 },
  { val: 5, count: 0 },
  { val: 6, count: 3 },
  { val: 7, count: 0 },
  { val: 8, count: 2 },
  { val: 9, count: 0 },
  { val: 0, count: 1 } ]
```

#### Array.prototype.map

Esta función te permite crear un nuevo Array a partir de los retornos obtenidos de cada uno de los elementos de un Array base al ser pasados a través de una función callback que tu implementes.

Puedes encontrar la documentación [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map).

#### Array.prototype.filter

Es una función que te permite crear un nuevo Array a partir de uno preexistente, usando una función callback que te permita evaluar si el dato sera removido (en caso de que la función resulte en falsa) o mantenido (en caso de que la función retorne verdadero).

Puedes encontrar la documentación [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter).

#### Observación

El problema de resolver la situación de esta forma es que estamos realizando la cantidad de ciclos equivalente a la cantidad de elementos del Array 1 multiplicado por la cantidad de elementos del Array 2, es decir en este caso que nuestro `arr1` tiene 10 elementos y nuestro `arr2` tiene 9 elementos, entonces vamos a realizar 90 recorridos.

### Solución B

Por otro lado puedes obtener de una forma mas eficiente aunque compleja el resultado esperado haciendo uso de las funciones `Array.prototype.reduce` y `Array.prototype.map` de la siguiente forma:

```
const counts = arr2.reduce((prev, cur, idx) => {
    if (idx === 1) {
        const prevObj = { [prev]: 1 }
        return {
            ...prevObj,
            [cur]: (typeof prevObj[cur] !== 'undefined' ? (prevObj[cur] + 1) : 1)
        }
    }
    return {
        ...prev,
        [cur]: (typeof prev[cur] !== 'undefined' ? (prev[cur] + 1) : 1)
    }
})

const res = arr1.map(val => ({
    val,
    count: (typeof counts[val] !== 'undefined' ? counts[val] : 0)
}))

console.log(res)
```

#### Array.prototype.reduce

Es una función acumuladora que te permite tomar los valores de izquierda a derecha de un Array y transformarlos a un único valor aplicándo una funcion callback.

Puedes encontrar la documentación [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce).

#### Observación

Esta solución es mucho mas eficiente debido a que el numero de ciclos que realizamos es equivalente solo a la cantidad de elementos de nuestro `arr1` mas la cantidad de elementos de nuestro `arr2` es decir 19.

### Demostración

Si realizamos un perfilamiento del código por medio de la API de performance podemos notar unos resultados similares a los siguientes:

```
[ { val: 1, count: 0 },
  { val: 2, count: 2 },
  { val: 3, count: 0 },
  { val: 4, count: 1 },
  { val: 5, count: 0 },
  { val: 6, count: 3 },
  { val: 7, count: 0 },
  { val: 8, count: 2 },
  { val: 9, count: 0 },
  { val: 0, count: 1 } ]
Solucion A performance: 3.8110360000282526
[ { val: 1, count: 0 },
  { val: 2, count: 2 },
  { val: 3, count: 0 },
  { val: 4, count: 1 },
  { val: 5, count: 0 },
  { val: 6, count: 3 },
  { val: 7, count: 0 },
  { val: 8, count: 2 },
  { val: 9, count: 0 },
  { val: 0, count: 1 } ]
Solucion B performance: 0.31593700032681227
```

Te dejo el código que use para realizar el perfilamiento con nodejs v.10.15.0 a continuación:

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks')

let startTime
let endTime
let elapsedTime

const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
const arr2 = [2,2,4,6,6,6,8,8,0]

// Solucion A

startTime = performance.now()

const res1 = arr1.map(val => ({ val, count: arr2.filter(subval => subval === val).length }))

console.log(res1)

endTime = performance.now()
elapsedTime = endTime - startTime

console.log(`Solucion A performance: ${elapsedTime}`)

// Solucion B

startTime = performance.now()

const counts = arr2.reduce((prev, cur, idx) => {
    if (idx === 1) {
        const prevObj = { [prev]: 1 }
        return {
            ...prevObj,
            [cur]: (typeof prevObj[cur] !== 'undefined' ? (prevObj[cur] + 1) : 1)
        }
    }
    return {
        ...prev,
        [cur]: (typeof prev[cur] !== 'undefined' ? (prev[cur] + 1) : 1)
    }
})

const res2 = arr1.map(val => ({
    val,
    count: (typeof counts[val] !== 'undefined' ? counts[val] : 0)
}))

console.log(res2)

endTime = performance.now()
elapsedTime = endTime - startTime

console.log(`Solucion B performance: ${elapsedTime}`)
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, muy bien documentada, código muy limpio, y con la comparación de los tiempos. ¡Te felicito! Y te agradezco también :-)

Comment: Gracias amigo, espero haber sido de ayuda :)

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que es javascript. Se me ocurren dos forman. Una es usando un map en js. Y la otra es usando el doble bucle de tu código.

```
var array1=['18753933','18753933','18771982'];
var array2=['18753933','18771982'];

var result1 = {};

for(var i=0; i<array1.length;i++){
    if(result1.hasOwnProperty(array1[i])){
        result1[array1[i]]=result1[array1[i]]+1;
    }
    else{
        result1[array1[i]]=1;
    }
}
console.log(result1);

var result2=[];

for(var i=0;i<array2.length;i++)
{
    var cont=0;
    for(var j=0;j<array1.length;j++){
        if(array2[i]===array1[j]){
            cont++;
        }
    }
    result2.push({num:array2[i],cont:cont});
}
console.log(result2);
```

Habrá algunas diferencias en la forma de impresión de los datos del console.log.